# cron job for running php script on openshift

Tags: php, cron, openshift

I have an Openshift PHP app which have  folders for cron job

[image: cron snip]

I have update.sh file in *minutely* directory, I want to execute a Php script after every minute as

```
#!/bin/bash
php http://myapp.rhcloud.com/update_rate.php
```

update_rate.php script is

```
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$txt = "THis is ".date("Y/m/d")." date ";
fwrite($myfile, $txt);
fclose($myfile);
```

but it does not run the cron job and does not create file in minutely folder at all, any suggestions to run cron job successfully on openshift.com

Comment: You trying to do this on windows? Did you `README.cron`?

Comment: I'm pushing to the server and fetching the _newfile.txt_, but I can't find that file, I'm sure cron job is not running/executing there..

Comment: You should add you cronjobs by using `crontab -e` and then add them. You can check its running by looking at `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: An example will be life saving for me, please give me any reference

Comment: tried _crontab -e_ it gives _crontab: command not found_ message

Comment: See: https://blog.openshift.com/getting-started-with-cron-jobs-on-openshift/ - The bash script wont run anyway, as `php http://myapp.rhcloud.com/update_rate.php` should be `php /local/path/to/update_rate.php`

Comment: Sorry Man could not get correctly, any example which is very clear for beginners??